# ADB (android debug bridge) is unresponsive on Linux (Pop!_OS) with newest kernel

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

Any command I try to execute just results in the shell hanging and not doing anything until I interrupt it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.  The below picture which illustrates the problem:

[image]

I've tried pretty much any solution I could find. This problem is NOT related to the android device.`sudo adb kill-server` has the same result as `adb devices` and I don't know how or where to start looking for Problems as anything like "debugging adb" or "troubleshooting adb" just pulls up tons of results of troubleshooting and debugging **with** adb.

I've already tried to reinstall adb, anything related to adb, and openjdk.

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER:

some Java process was running and blocking ipv6 localhost, this caused ADB to basically just freeze because apparently it doesn't know what to do when the port it wants to use is blocked.

STEPS TO RESOLVE:

run with sudo (install net-tools via yum, apt etc. if not already installed):

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w '5037'
```

this will show you the process ID of the process on port 5037 eg. 12345/foobar

then kill the process. Ideally only if you know it isn't a critical Process! run with sudo if necessary

```
kill 12345
```